# Как добавить исключения для бота ,чтобы он не удалял сообщения с ссылками от администратора

Tags: python, удаление

Добавил код для бота ,чтобы он удалял все сообщения с ссылками, как можно добавить исключение, чтобы он не удалял сообщения с ссылками от администратора группы?

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id == GROUP_ID)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        else:
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически вы можете просто добавить вот такую проверку в функцию:

`if message.author != 'your username':`

А также разрешения, отправленные автором сообщения, могут быть повторно получены методом `message.author.permissions_in` . Он принимает объект канала в качестве параметра и возвращает список объектов разрешений, поэтому вам нужно только проверить, есть ли в нем разрешение администратора. Кроме того, роли, которые автор отправил сообщение, хранятся в `message.author.roles` . Это просто список с объектами ролей, чтобы вы могли проверить, есть ли в нем роль администратора.

Comment: Не помогло, возможно не туда вставляю его, куда его вставить?

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая ваш код, то должно быть примерно так:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.entities is not None and message.chat.id == GROUP_ID)
def delete_links(message):
    for entity in message.entities:
        if entity.type in ["url", "text_link"]:
            if message.author != 'your username':
                bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        else:
            return
```